# Trying to convert and display an ordinal number

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Enter a number"
i = gets.chomp.to_i

def ordinal(n)
   last_number = n % 10
   special_case = n.to_s

   if special_case.include?("11") || special_case.include?("12") || special_case.include?("13")
      return "th"
   elseif last_number == 1
      return "st"
   elseif last_number == 2
      return "nd"
   elseif last_number == 3
      return "rd"
   else
      return "th"
   end
end

puts "That's the #{i}#{ordinal(i)} item!"
```

Can't figure out why each answer returns `"th"`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Aside from replacing `elseif` with `elsif`, suppose `n = 21131`. Then

```
special_case = n.to_s
  #=> "21131"
special_case.include?("11")
  #=> true
```

which is not what you want.

Consider writing your method as follows:

```
def ordinal(n)
  return "th" if (11..13).include? n%100
  case n%10
  when 1 then "st"
  when 2 then "nd"
  when 3 then "rd"
  else        "th"
  end
end

puts "Enter a number"
n = gets.to_i
```

Note `chomp` is not needed because, for example, `"23cats".to_i #=> 23`.

```
n = 211
That's the 211th item!

n = 282
puts "That's the #{n}#{ordinal(n)} item!" 
That's the 282nd item!

n = 24733
puts "That's the #{n}#{ordinal(n)} item!" 
That's the 24733rd item!
```

There's a problem. The last of these, for example, should be, "That's the 14 thousand, seven hundred thirty-third item!". You could modify the method to return this string, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's elsif, not elseif, also in one case you compare with a string, in the other with a number. You don't have to convert to a string to do the comparisons.

Your methods should be something like

```
def ordinal(n)
   last_number = n % 10
   if [11,12,13].include?last_number
      return "th"
   elsif last_number == 1
      return "st"
   elsif last_number == 2
      return "nd"
   elsif last_number == 3
      return "rd"
   else
      return "th"
   end
end
```

If the result is correct, I wouldn't know, English is not my mothers language.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  So it that just a way to simplify the code?

Comment: @ballgame168 simpler = shorter = less change for mistakes = more readble = a better program = faster = more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result by using `case` statement.

```
puts "Enter a number"
i = gets.chomp.to_i

def ordinal(n)
  last_number = n % 10
  case 
    when last_number == 1 && n != 11 then return "st"
    when last_number == 2 && n != 12 then return "nd"
    when last_number == 3 && n != 13 then return "rd"
    else return "th"
  end
end

puts "That's the #{i}#{ordinal(i)} item!"
```

Hope this helps :)